# Create Web Service from struts2 Web Application

Tags: web-services, web-applications, struts2

First, I'm new to Web Services. I have a didactical task at university about developing web application and web service for something like managing distribuited drug stores. 
I've developed a working Web Application using struts2 framework, but now I'd like to extend it to a Web Service. I found that I could implement a class (named for example WSManager) which is a wrapper of the various Web App Controllers. 
It would have to make calls to static methods of those Controllers. Web Application is designed to provide a Controller for each use case.

for example a Controller is like this:

```java
public class AdminLocaleController extends AbstractController {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6266455088438602574L;
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AdminLocaleController.class);

private List<Prodotto> prodotti;

@Override
public String execute() {
    prodotti = initializeAdminLocaleView();
    return "success";
}

public List<Prodotto> getProdotti() {
    return prodotti;
}

public void setProdotti(List<Prodotto> prodotti) {
    this.prodotti = prodotti;
}

public static List<Prodotto> initializeAdminLocaleView() {
            logger.info("Recupero lista di prodotti da ordinare");
    DBController dbController = new DBControllerImpl();
    return dbController.getProdottiDaOrdinare();
}

}
```

and the WSManager class makes a call to the initializeAdminLocaleView(), just like this:

```
/* AdminLocaleController */
public List<Prodotto> initializeAdminLocaleView(){
    return AdminLocaleController.initializeAdminLocaleView();
}
```

I would create a Web Service in Eclipse providing that service class.

If I'm doing something wrong I ask you the proper way to extend the web application to a web service.

Otherwise, my matter is if I have to (and how to) manage parameters and attributes between Views (jsp) and Controllers.

Finally I have some Controllers (each of these implement SessionAware) which process data and store returned object in Session (for example a LoginController which saves a User bean in request session). Deeper, my question is how I should manage Web App's **session stored attributes** in case of a Web Service. If I have method calls in WSManager which passes a User bean as parameters, how could I obtain it from a session. Or simply, do I have necessity of obtaining something from a session from a Web Service perspective?

I'm sure I've written a confusionary question, but confusionary is my state of mind at this point too.

Comment: what kind of web-serices you are looking for, if you use struts2 rest plugin its gives you REST type resources.Have a look at following tutorial http://blog.mersoft.com/2009/09/08/struts2-rest-webservice/

Comment: If you can get away with json producing services, then I would create a new package in struts.xml and start mapping your existing actions. If your actions provide the required inputs and output all ready you might find that you really have very little to do at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints. I'll try them